# Recursive pass parameters into a function in R?

Tags: r

Assume

`group <- c("A0", "A1")` then `getValue(A1 - A0)`

`group <- c("A0", "A1", "A2")` then `getValue(A1 - A0, A2 - A0)`

`group <- c("A0", "A1", "A2", "A3")` then `getValue(A1 - A0, A2 - A0, A3 - A0)`

If I have `group <- c("A0", "A1", ..., "A100")` then `getValue(A1 - A0, ..., A100 - A0)`

I would like to know how to **automatically** pass the values of `group` into `getValue()` like in the above three examples, rather than write them one by one manually?

For example, I have `group <- c("A0", "A1", ..., "A1000")`, how to pass these values into `getValue()` function?

Thanks.

Comment: What are `A0`, `A1`? You can not subtract characters.

Comment: `getValue(Map(\`-\`, mget(group[-1]), mget(group[1])))`? You should make your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610), though.

Comment: I learn this function `makeContrasts {limma}`. Now I know that `contrasts` argument can do the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to use non-standard evaluation via `eval`, `parse`

```
group <- paste0("A", seq_len(101)-1)
cmdstr <- paste0("getValue(", 
    paste(paste(group[-1], group[1], sep=" - "), collapse=", "), 
    ")" )
cmdstr
eval(parse(text=cmdstr))
```

Just curious, why does the getValue function require increasing number of variables rather than taking in a list?

Comment: thanks @chinsoon12. Your answer can solve my problem.   In fact, I learn this function `makeContrasts {limma}`. Now I know that `contrasts` argument can do the same thing

Comment: `eval(parse())` very good.